# Add a whitespace before the provider icon

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, sign-up

The message in register new account dialog using 3d-party provider has no whitespace before the provider's icon:

> [image: Google]

> [image: Facebook]

I think this should be fixed.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this one. Is there an ad / social blocker that might be trolling you here?

Comment: @AaronShekey I'm also able to reproduce with on my phone's Chrome browser. No blocker is used.

Comment: @AaronShekey could you please post screenshot with no issue?

Comment: I was able to [reproduce this using Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfvxG.png)

Comment: I can also reproduce on the latest version of both Firefox and Chrome. MacOS 10.13.6

Comment: Also, shouldn't there be whitespace before AND after the icon? Not just before.

Comment: @KodosJohnson or instead the logo :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it! This was a whitespace issue that I was having trouble reproducing in our dev environment. Thanks for reporting this! It'll go live after the next build, whenever that is!

[image]

Comment: Nice plug for [literature.se] :-P